# Trying to remove the marker after a certain amount of time on leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I want the map to be up to date so that the markers users added are removed after 30min (using 3sec to test it in the code). Tried "removeMarkerTimeOut" but got no response.

```
function getClickedLanLon(e) {
  var lat, lon, zoom;

  lat = e.latlng.lat;
  lon = e.latlng.lng;
  zoom = map.getZoom();

  marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(lat, lon), { icon: CF });
  map.addLayer(marker);
  marker.bindPopup("Cat spotted").addTo(map);
}

map.on("click", getClickedLanLon);

let removeMarkerTimeOut = setTimeout(
  {
    marker: removeFrom(map),
  },
  3000
).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout carefully.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to remove the marker, remove the actual layer that you created with the marker.

```
map.removeLayer(marker)
```

So in your Timeout case:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    map.removeLayer(marker)
}, 5000);
```

To my knowledge and according to some github posts by liedman, there is no such thing as removeFrom.